# Is there any alternative for white-space:nowrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using textarea with `white-space:nowrap` this will works fine and removing spaces but this is adding horizontal scrollbar to text.
I dont want horizontal scrollbar. If i used `overflow-x:hidden` scrollbar is invisible but by arrow key I can scroll.
I want fix width of text area after that width the data should come to next line and text area should remove extra white spaces also and no horizontal scrolling
how to achieve this?

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of your code? This isn't very clear.

Comment: "data should come to next line" - so you **want** to have wrap?  Then just remove `white-space:nowrap` and you're done.   What's the problem here?

Comment: if I remove white-space:nowrap then if there are multiple spaces between words then they are not getting replace to 1

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `white-space:pre-line` or `white-space:normal`.

```css
textarea { 
   width:100%;
   height:200px;
}
.normal {
   white-space:normal;
}
.pre-line {
   white-space:pre-line;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="normal">Lorem ipsum    dolor    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</textarea>

<textarea class="pre-line">Lorem ipsum    dolor    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</textarea>
```